# NLP approach for classifying webscraped data

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, text-classification

I have a challenge in a project of mine where I will be provided with a list of scraped datas from a website. Along with the data i will also be provided some parameters like the tag of scraped element, class name of the scraped element and some preceeding texts. My job is to provide the best suited column name that suits the data. I am able to extract some relevant data from the class name but surety is required because that's not a reliable factor.

So, I require a method or approach of classifying the datas provided. I am considering spacy and its features like NER etc. Kindly provide an approach. Other technically feasible solutions are also welcomed!!!!!!

Things I have tried:- The default NER of spacy and sklearns classifier but the classifier wasnt showing any good result and the spacys default NER is a lot limited. A custom NER requires a good amount of data. So all i need is an approach to move ahead with. I am also unsure if i should consider the text classification. Because my ultimate goal is to ensure the category provided suits the scraped data. The scraped data can be varied:- list of job listings, real estates, products, titles of books, link or urls etc.